# String concatenate null value and retrieve null value java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, java-8, stream

I am using Stream.of to concatenate a couple of string values with the separator of ":", one of them can be null, but when I retrieve it to an array of strings, I want to have a fixed number of elements in that array. I'd like to know which one in the string array is null.
For instance, I have concatenated a string by using

```
Stream.of("abc", "def", "ghi", null)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(":"));
```

It will be "abc:def:ghi:null". Then split it into array of strings, I use

```
final String[] strings = "abc:def:ghi:null".split(":");
```

But the strings[3] is "null" instead of null. Is there a way to cast "null" to null value?

Comment: What happens if a value is legitimately `"null"`? For example, there are people named `Null`.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the `null` mapping as a post processing :

```
String[] strings =  "abc:def:ghi:null".split(":");
strings = Arrays.stream(strings).map(s-> s.equals("null")? null : s).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(strings[3] == null);
```

prints `true`.

Note that here you don't know if `null` or the `"null"` String was used at the origin in the stream as you cannot differentiate them once you joined the String .

Answer (score 2):

String `"null"` is not `null`. You need to filter your result:

```
final String[] strings = Arrays.stream("abc:def:ghi:null".split(":")).filter(str -> str.equals("null")).toArray(String::new);
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I did not read it correctly. If you want to map `"null"`, to `null`, then simply:

```
final String[] strings = Arrays.stream("abc:def:ghi:null".split(":")).map(str -> str == "null" ? null : str).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: This will end up having IndexOutOfBounds if I use strings[3], I'd like to know the value of last element, either null or non-null

Comment: Right, I have corrected the answer, I need to sleep better, I have problems reading :)

Comment: Are you sure you can use `str == "null"` in Java? They may not be the same object, even if they are the same value.

Comment: Ok, maybe equals would be more consistent, but as far as i know, `String`s are interned, so that the operator `==` has the same effect as `equals` method.